# What is the most efficient way to loop on properties in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Is there a way I can achieve this code in a more efficient way ? because looping on a very big scores array just to find one score property is very costly

```
var scores = [{scoredBy:"youssef",score:5},{scoredBy:"omar",score:3}];

scores.forEach(score=>{
    if(score.scoredBy == "youssef"){
      console.log(score);
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe use a loop structure you can break on a match.

Comment: @Teemu Adding a return statement in the conditional should be enough

Comment: @Sebastianb not with forEach....

Comment: uff, I'm still asleep!

Comment: Don't use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control), use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficient way would be to use an object instead of an array where the key is the scoredBy value. No looping, just a lookup.

```js
var scores = { "youssef" : 5, "omar":3 };
console.log(scores["youssef"])
```

Other ways

- [for of loop with break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [array find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control)

```js
var scores = [{scoredBy:"youssef",score:5},{scoredBy:"omar",score:3}];

for (const value of scores) {
  if (value.scoredBy==="youssef") {
    console.log(value.score);
    break;
  }
}
```

```js
var scores = [{scoredBy:"youssef",score:5},{scoredBy:"omar",score:3}];

var result = scores.find( value => value.scoredBy==="youssef")
console.log(result.score);
```